# what the correct if-condition for my excel file?

Tags: excel, vba

I want the specific cells to be functioning by double-clicking and if this cell is on the first column, and row bigger than 12.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target.Columns = 1 And Target.Row >= 12 Then
        dateVariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
        Target = dateVariable
    End If

End Sub
```

but it seems the condition that I mentioned aren't correct. cuz code working without this condition properly.

Comment: `Target.Column`, not `.Columns`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To supplement @BigBen's answer...

`Range.Columns` returns a `Range` representing the columns in the specified range (here `Target`). By checking `If Target.Columns = 1` you're making an implicit default member call against the returned `Range` object, i.e. `If Target.Columns.[_Defaut] = 1`, which yields `Target.Columns.Value`, which is a 2D variant array - which can't be compared to a `1` literal.

Thus, the error you're getting is a *type mismatch* error, because VBA can't compare a 2D variant array to an integer literal and successfully evaluate a result.

You want `Range.Column` (singular), which returns the column number for the left-most cell in the specified `Range`.

Comment: Yes, this is great additional detail. Well, maybe not additional, *essential* to the explanation.

Comment: Was midway through my draft when I saw your answer pop up, debated whether to post it or not.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You want `Target.Column`, not `.Columns`.

From the documentation:

- [`Range.Column`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.column) property:

  > Returns the **number** of the first column in the first area in the specified range.
- [`Range.Columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columns) property:

  > Returns a **Range** object that represents the columns in the specified range.

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment on @Mathieu's answer (not enough reputation yet), you should also check if you only have one cell selected. This might not be much useful in case of a double click event, but, there will be a time that you will reuse this code to another intent (maybe for the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event), where this event can be fired by a multiple selection. In this case, the Column value will return the left most column. If it fits the `.Column =1` criteria, then all your selection will be filled with the date, which might be frustrating if you loose data in your table.

So, remember to simply add `And Target.Count = 1` to your `If` statement.

PS : It's good practice to force the VBA IDE to required [explicit variable declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html), I'm surprise Mathieu didn't point this out. Also, your use of the `dateVariable` variable is not necessary. Just use `Target = CalendarForm.GetDate` or even better : `Target.Value = CalendarForm.GetDate`

Comment: Uvoted for calling me out on not pointing out the obviously missing `Option Explicit` and the undeclared variables :-)  ....and congrats, you can now comment everywhere!

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon! ;)